# With the removal of rowr Package, how can i create a dataframe of inequal length?

Tags: r, package, cbind

I know that's a pretty commun question but, I was using the **cbind.fill** function from the **rowr** package to create a data frame with vector of inequal length. But with the removal of this package recently, I failed to find another way to do it

Is there a backup function that can replace **cbind.fill** ?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: There might be another function in a different package that can do this but the source of rowr is here if you just want to copy the function - it is only a few lines long with no depedencies (I think) https://github.com/cvarrichio/rowr/blob/master/R/rowr.R#L106-L113

Comment: Thanks for your anwser ! I found the **cbind.na** from the **qpcR** package that do the same thing !